# Get user status using PubNub

Tags: android, pubnub

I have created an application that implements app to app calling using Sinch. It works only when the caller knows the name of the recipient.

To overcome this Sinch suggested to use PubNub to get the user state. They also have a [tutorial here.](https://www.sinch.com/tutorials/user-presence-system-tutorial/) The problem is that tutorial is old and PubNub has updated their API since. I tried to implement the functionality using their new API on my own using their docs, but it is not working or more accurately I don't know how to do it.

My current code is:

```java
public class LoggedUsers extends Activity {
    private PubNub pubNub;
    String name;
    private ArrayList users;
    private JSONArray loggedUserList;
    ListView UserList;
    TextView allUsers;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.user_list);
        allUsers = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.JSONFromPubNub);
        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("User_Details", MODE_APPEND);
        try {
            name = sp.getString("UserName", "");
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {

        }
        final PNConfiguration pnc = new PNConfiguration();
        pnc.setPublishKey("publish key");
        pnc.setSubscribeKey("subscribe key");
        pnc.setUuid(name);

        pubNub = new PubNub(pnc);
        users = new ArrayList<String>();
        UserList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        String user = getUserStatus();
        allUsers.setText(user);
        final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.single_item_list, users);
        UserList.setAdapter(adapter);

        pubNub.addListener(new SubscribeCallback() {
            @Override
            public void status(PubNub pubnub, PNStatus status) {
                if (status.getCategory() == PNStatusCategory.PNUnexpectedDisconnectCategory) {
                    // This event happens when radio / connectivity is lost
                    HashMap <String,String> map = new HashMap();
                    map.put("State","Offline");
                    pubNub.setPresenceState().channels(Arrays.asList("CallingChannel1")).state(map).uuid(pnc.getUuid());
                } else if (status.getCategory() == PNStatusCategory.PNConnectedCategory) {

                    // Connect event. You can do stuff like publish, and know you'll get it.
                    // Or just use the connected event to confirm you are subscribed for
                    // UI / internal notifications, etc
                    HashMap <String,String> map = new HashMap();
                    map.put("State","Online");
                    pubNub.setPresenceState().channels(Arrays.asList("CallingChannel1")).state(map).uuid(pnc.getUuid());
                  /*  if (status.getCategory() == PNStatusCategory.PNConnectedCategory) {
                        pubnub.publish().channel("awesomeChannel").message("hello!!").async(new PNCallback<PNPublishResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(PNPublishResult result, PNStatus status) {
                                // Check whether request successfully completed or not.
                                if (!status.isError()) {

                                    // Message successfully published to specified channel.
                                }
                                // Request processing failed.
                                else {

                                    // Handle message publish error. Check 'category' property to find out possible issue
                                    // because of which request did fail.
                                    //
                                    // Request can be resent using: [status retry];
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }*/
                } else if (status.getCategory() == PNStatusCategory.PNReconnectedCategory) {
                    HashMap <String,String> map = new HashMap();
                    map.put("State","Online");
                    pubNub.setPresenceState().channels(Arrays.asList("CallingChannel1")).state(map).uuid(pnc.getUuid());

                    // Happens as part of our regular operation. This event happens when
                    // radio / connectivity is lost, then regained.
                } else if (status.getCategory() == PNStatusCategory.PNDecryptionErrorCategory) {

                    // Handle messsage decryption error. Probably client configured to
                    // encrypt messages and on live data feed it received plain text.
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void message(PubNub pubnub, PNMessageResult message) {

            }

            @Override
            public void presence(PubNub pubnub, PNPresenceEventResult presence) {

            }
        });
    }
    public String getUserStatus(){
        final StringBuilder allUsers = new StringBuilder();
        pubNub.subscribe().channels(Arrays.asList("CallingChannel1")).withPresence().execute();
        pubNub.hereNow()
                // tailor the next two lines to example
                .channels(Arrays.asList("CallingChannel1"))
                .includeState(true)
                .includeUUIDs(true)
                .async(new PNCallback<PNHereNowResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(PNHereNowResult result, PNStatus status) {
                        if (status.isError()) {
                            // handle error
                            return;
                        }

                        for (PNHereNowChannelData channelData : result.getChannels().values()) {
                            allUsers.append("---");
                            allUsers.append("channel:" + channelData.getChannelName());
                            allUsers.append("occoupancy: " + channelData.getOccupancy());
                            allUsers.append("occupants:");
                            for (PNHereNowOccupantData occupant : channelData.getOccupants()) {
                                allUsers.append("uuid: " + occupant.getUuid() + " state: " + occupant.getState());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
               return allUsers.toString();
    }



    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

Here are my problems:

1. I am trying to display all the data that I receive in a textview (later it will arranged in a listview or a recycler view) but I am getting a blank screen so I am getting null from the server.
2. The user status should be constantly updated to know if the user changes state (online -> offline) but there seems to be no `async` calls made in the code so I think it will be executed only once and then the dataset is not being changed.

How can I solve my problems?

Comment: You can monitor online and state changes using Presence. When you subscribe, subscribe with presence enabled and you will get `state-change`, `join`, `leave` & `timeout` events in the `presence` callback of the `listener`. Let me know if that leads you in the right direction.

Comment: @CraigConover I will check into it. Basically I am going to populate a listview with users who are online(connected to the internet and have my app running in the foreground or in background) and I am going to update the list asynchronously so the users main activities do not get affected.

Comment: @cjensen.. I just wanted to let you guys know that the tutorial is out of date, it will be helpful if you updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## PubNub Presence

You can monitor online and state changes using [PubNub Presence](https://www.pubnub.com/products/presence/). When you subscribe, subscribe with presence enabled and you will get `state-change`, `join`, `leave` & `timeout` [events in the `presence` callback](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/android-java/presence#receiving_presence_join_leave).

```java
Callback callback = new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void successCallback(String channel, Object message) {
        System.out.println(channel + " : "
                + message.getClass() + " : " + message.toString());

       // take action on the presence events here
    }
 
    @Override
    public void connectCallback(String channel, Object message) {
       System.out.println("CONNECT on channel:" + channel
                + " : " + message.getClass() + " : "
                + message.toString());
    }
 
    @Override
    public void disconnectCallback(String channel, Object message) {
        System.out.println("DISCONNECT on channel:" + channel
                + " : " + message.getClass() + " : "
                + message.toString());
    }
 
    @Override
    public void reconnectCallback(String channel, Object message) {
        System.out.println("RECONNECT on channel:" + channel
                + " : " + message.getClass() + " : "
                + message.toString());
    }
 
    @Override
    public void errorCallback(String channel, PubnubError error) {
        System.out.println("ERROR on channel " + channel
                + " : " + error.toString());
    }
};
 
try {
    pubnub.presence("my_channel", callback);
} 
catch (PubnubException e) {
    System.out.println(e.toString());
}
```

It appears Sinch is using a rather old version of the PubNub Android SDK. I would think you could still use [PubNub Android SDK v4](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/java/pubnub-java-sdk-v4) to do what you need to do outside of Sinch SDK unless there is some explicit requirements by Sinch to use the same version of the SDK.

Comment: I will try this and let you know the result.